# How to connect to 2 different data sources from Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Is it possible to connect to 2 different data sources from Power BI Desktop at the same time to design one report?

I have 2 different data sources ( SQL Server & Oracle) to fetch data using Power BI and create a common report.

please suggest any possibility or any work around if there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to connect to more than one [data sources and types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources). You can mix and match modes as well, you can import data, or use [direct query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery) to allow a connection to the data sources. SQL Server will have a native driver in Power BI, for Oracle please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database)